# Flatness implies equi-dimensional fibres

Tags: algebraic-geometry, flatness

This is in reference to [Intuition for when modules are flat](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1502957/intuition-for-when-modules-are-flat/1503069) and the MO https://mathoverflow.net/questions/259574/flatness-from-constancy-of-dimension-of-fibers.

My question is as follows. Assume $M$ is a flat module over some commutative ring $R$. For any prime ideal $p \subset R$, we have a $k(p)$-vector space $M \otimes_R k(p)$, where $k(p)$ is the residue field $k(p) = R_p / p R_p$. Is the dimension of this space independent from $p$, knowing that $M$ is flat (and perhaps further assumptions)?

The motivation is that I am trying to understand flatness in algebraic geometry. If we have a flat morphism of (say affine) schemes
$$ \pi : X= \text{Spec } M \rightarrow \text{Spec } R = Y$$

then the fibres over any point $p \in Spec R$ are given by 
$$ X \times_Y \text{Spec } k(p) = \text{Spec }(M \otimes_R k(p)) .$$

Saying that $\pi$ is flat is identical to saying that $M$ is flat over $R$, thus my interest in 
$$ \dim_{k(p)} M \otimes_R k(p) .$$

Comment: The answer to the question in the pargraph beginning "My question..." is no. Let  $k$ be a field. Consider $R=k[x]$ and $M=k[x,x^{-1}$. Let $p=(x)$ and $q=(x-1)$, then $M\otimes_R k(p)=0$, but $M\otimes_R k(q)=k$.

Comment: It is important to note that the dimension you use in taking about dimension fibres, is not the same dimension as talking about dimension of  vector spaces

Comment: @user45150 Thanks for answering. There was a big typo in my question: I'm asking whether the dimension of the vector space is independent, not the space itself. I'm also aware that the usual use of `fibre dimension' is not the one I'm using right now. I'm talking about the dimension as a vector space. Now clarified!

Comment: @user45150 I see that your answer also gives a negative answer to the dimension question, but I'm confused as to why it doesn't contradict the posts I referred to. The first gives an example and states that non-equidimensional dimension implies the module is not flat, and the second seems to imply that a flat, finitely presented, reduced module has equidimensional fibres. What is going on?

Comment: Concerning your confusion about the example $k[T]\to k[T^\pm]$: the precise statement is https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02JS and you need a point in the fiber to start with.