# What is interesting about the support of a module?

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

In Commutative Algebra, we defined the *Support of a Module* $M$
$$ \operatorname{Supp}(M) = \{P \in \operatorname{Spec}(R) : M_P \neq \{0 \} \} = \{P \in \operatorname{Spec}(R): \exists m \in M: \operatorname{Ann}(m) \subseteq P \} $$
Today, I asked our tutor "Can you tell us why $\operatorname{Supp}(M)$ is interesting?" and he told me no, that he has never really seen it in action.

So I want to pose this question here. Why should $\operatorname{Supp}(M)$ be interesting?

Comment: For finitely generated modules the dimension of M is the supremum of the lengths of chains of primes in Supp(M).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules. Then the support of $\mathcal{F}$ is all the points of $X$ "where the stalk is non-zero", i.e.
$$\mathrm{supp}(\mathcal{F}) = \{ x \in X \mid \mathcal{F}_x \neq 0 \}. $$
This indeed coincides with the definition you've given in your question. Note that one can generalise this notion to complexes of sheaves, i.e.
$$ \mathrm{supp}(\mathcal{F}^\bullet) = \bigcup \mathrm{supp}(H^i(\mathcal{F}^\bullet)). $$ 
Then this notion is important in stating/proving many results from algebraic geometry. For example, if we know somthing like $x \notin \mathrm{supp}(\mathcal{F}^\bullet) $ then we can deduce that $\mathcal{F}^\bullet |_U$ is trivial, where $x \in U \subset X$ is an open neighbourhood of $x$.

Comment: I do not yet know what a sheaf is but this answer seems really nice. I will definitely come back to it when I study Algebraic Geometry! Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! Algebraic geometry realises many concepts like this from commutative algebra in very nice geometric ways so this will be indeed good to come back to. Another nice example is the [geometry behind flat modules](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1502957/intuition-for-when-modules-are-flat/1503069).

Comment: Awesome. I am looking forward to that; thank you for the link!

Comment: I can finally understand that this was the correct answer! (And I'm thinking I might have misinterpreted my tutor's answer, or I would at least be really surprised that he doesn't know such a basic notion.)